# Match patterns, add newline and append word to end of line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Can somebody assist in helping me solve this problem. I have a file that I've extracted and the file contents look like this.

```
(11213068, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075227404, 2021-06-14) added
(11213177, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075227413, 2021-06-14) added
(11213070, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075193958, 2021-05-28) added
(1075194668, 2022-11-29) added
(1073757334, 2021-01-20) (1073757337, 2021-01-20) (1073757349, 2021-01-20) (1073757331, 2021-01-20) (1073757346, 2021-01-20) added
(1073757237, 2020-11-20) (1073757263, 2020-11-20) (1073757233, 2020-11-20) (1073757241, 2020-11-20) (1073757247, 2020-11-20) deleted
```

++ My desired results for the file would look like this --

```
(11213068, 2020-11-16) delete
(1075227404, 2021-06-14) add
(11213177, 2020-11-16) delete
(1075227413, 2021-06-14) add
(11213070, 2020-11-16) delete
(1075193958, 2021-05-28) add
(1075194668, 2022-11-29) add
(1073757334, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757337, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757349, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757331, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757346, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757237, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757263, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757233, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757241, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757247, 2020-11-20) delete
```

On the last 2 lines I am unable to figure out a solution. My output using this command --

```
awk '$3!="added"' | awk '$3!="deleted"' | sed 's/) (/\n/g' file.txt
```

```
(11213068, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075227404, 2021-06-14) added
(11213177, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075227413, 2021-06-14) added
(11213070, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075193958, 2021-05-28) added
(1075194668, 2022-11-29) added
(1073757334, 2021-01-20
1073757337, 2021-01-20
1073757349, 2021-01-20
1073757331, 2021-01-20
1073757346, 2021-01-20) added
(1073757237, 2020-11-20
1073757263, 2020-11-20
1073757233, 2020-11-20
1073757241, 2020-11-20
1073757247, 2020-11-20) deleted
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Use the right delimiter for this.

```
awk -F') ' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i FS $NF}' file
```

If you need to replace the last field, there are many ways to do it, for example using `sub()` at the beginning of the line processing.

```
awk -F') ' '{sub(/added$/,"add"); sub(/deleted$/,"delete"); for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i FS $NF}' file
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @Chinaj2020 If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

`GNU sed` with extensive regex mode `-E`.

- Mark regions sandwiched between `)` 
  `(`  with a newline marker. Then transport the last field (after it has been sanitized of its past tense) into the first marker, print upto the first marker, and then chop off upto the first marker. Repeat this process until we exhaust the pattern space.

---

```
$ sed -Ee '/\n/ba
    /e?d$/s/ (add|delete)e?d$/ \1/
    s/[)] [(]/) \n(/g;:a
    s/(\n.*)?\n.* (\S+)$/\2&/
    /\n.*\n/{P;D;}
' file
```

---

```
$ perl -F'\)\s' -lane '$, = ") ";
    my $l = pop(@F) =~
     s/^(add)ed$/$1/r =~
      s/^(delete)d$/$1/r;
    print $_, $l for @F;
' file
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a two-staged solution?

```
<infile sed 's/deleted/delete/; s/added/add/' | 
awk 'NF==3; NF>3 { for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1), $NF }'
```

Comment: You never need sed when youre using awk. `sed 's/deleted/delete/; s/added/add/' | awk 'foo'` = `awk '{sub(/deleted/,"delete"); sub(/added/,"add")} foo`

Comment: Indeed, but it looks cleaner

Comment: We'll very much have to agree to disagree on that point!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[(][^)]+)|\\S+' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, $NF}' file
(11213068, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075227404, 2021-06-14) added
(11213177, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075227413, 2021-06-14) added
(11213070, 2020-11-16) deleted
(1075193958, 2021-05-28) added
(1075194668, 2022-11-29) added
(1073757334, 2021-01-20) added
(1073757337, 2021-01-20) added
(1073757349, 2021-01-20) added
(1073757331, 2021-01-20) added
(1073757346, 2021-01-20) added
(1073757237, 2020-11-20) deleted
(1073757263, 2020-11-20) deleted
(1073757233, 2020-11-20) deleted
(1073757241, 2020-11-20) deleted
(1073757247, 2020-11-20) deleted
```

or if you really want to change those words at the end:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[(][^)]+)|\\S+' '
    BEGIN { map["deleted"]="delete"; map["added"]="add" }
    { for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, map[$NF] }
' file
(11213068, 2020-11-16) delete
(1075227404, 2021-06-14) add
(11213177, 2020-11-16) delete
(1075227413, 2021-06-14) add
(11213070, 2020-11-16) delete
(1075193958, 2021-05-28) add
(1075194668, 2022-11-29) add
(1073757334, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757337, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757349, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757331, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757346, 2021-01-20) add
(1073757237, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757263, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757233, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757241, 2020-11-20) delete
(1073757247, 2020-11-20) delete
```